# Python iteratively grep lines after a pattern in a file

Tags: python, file, parsing

I have a file that looks like:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Start
2, 0.001, 1.0
alpha = 0.001
beta = 1.3

...
...
...

new evaluation
complete
print out alpha & beta
alpha = 0.19
beta = 1.41
End

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Start
....
```

I would like to extract the three lines after "Start" and two lines after "print out". Basically, it should be:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2, 0.001, 1.0
alpha = 0.001
beta = 1.3

alpha = 0.19
beta = 1.41

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is what I used:

```
summary = open("summary_accuracy.txt","w")
content = []
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "Start" in line:
            content += [f.readline() for i in range(3)]
        if "print out" in line:
            content += [f.readline() for i in range(2)]
            content += "~~~~~~~~~~"

summary.write(content)
```

However, I got the error:

```
content += [f.readline() for i in range(3)]
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Comment: how about f.next()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `next(f)` instead of `f.readline()`.

Also consider using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) for this task:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'^Start\s(.*\s.*\s.*\s)', s, re.MULTILINE).group(1)
'2, 0.001, 1.0\nalpha = 0.001\nbeta = 1.3\n'
>>> re.search(r'^print out.*\s(.*\s.*\s)', s, re.MULTILINE).group(1)
'alpha = 0.19\nbeta = 1.41\n'
```

Comment: Or to let builtins do the whole of the work, `content += itertools.islice(f, 3)` (2 for the second use), which is just implicitly performing `next` three times (minor behavioral difference: It won't raise an error if the file runs out before you get the lines you need).

Comment: I think itertools are more straightforward. By the way, is there any simple way to do islice(f,-1)? I know the function does not accept negative arguments...